# How to get ROS2 parameter hosted by another Node

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters, rclpy, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been looking through the documentation and can not find any means to get or set parameters of other nodes than the one that has declared the parameters. Is this by design or is there a way to get the parameter with something like `node.get_parameter(other_node_name, parameter_name)`? I currently have parameters duplicated across configuration files because I can't figure out how to get the nodes to reach each others configurations. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am using ROS2 dashing.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340600/how-to-get-ros2-parameter-hosted-by-another-node/) by [mequi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49860/mequi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2019-12-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS 2 parameters are available via service interfaces:

```
root@d0a03d7984eb:/# ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener &
root@d0a03d7984eb:/# ros2 service list
/listener/describe_parameters
/listener/get_parameter_types
/listener/get_parameters
/listener/list_parameters
/listener/set_parameters
/listener/set_parameters_atomically
```

In `rclpy` I believe there is no helper and you need to create a service client yourself and call it, similar to [what is done in `ros2 service`](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/blob/c00dec0a72c049d3a4a8a80f1324ea24dc8373c6/ros2param/ros2param/api/__init__.py#L122)

In `rclcpp` there is are [ParameterClient classes](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/fdaf96f2171e70f3e013610aa44df2d7e9c866a3/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/parameter_client.hpp)
on which you can call functions like `get_parameters` and it will handle the service calls

the use looks like:

```
auto parameters_client = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(my_node, "remote_node_name");
while (!parameters_client->wait_for_service(1s)) {
  if (!rclcpp::ok()) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Interrupted while waiting for the service. Exiting.");
    rclcpp::shutdown();
  }
  RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "service not available, waiting again...");
}
auto parameters = parameters_client->get_parameters({"remote_param1", "remote_param2"});
```

you can then access them:

```
std::stringstream ss;
// Get a few of the parameters just set.
for (auto & parameter : parameters)
{
  ss << "\nParameter name: " << parameter.get_name();
  ss << "\nParameter value (" << parameter.get_type_name() << "): " <<
    parameter.value_to_string();
}
```

There is also a non-blocking / asynchronous version `rclcpp::AsyncParametersClient`

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lin404](https://answers.ros.org/users/50033/lin404/) on 2020-02-05**:
@marguedas I tried it with rclpy, but no luck. Do you mind to give me a sample in python for this? Also, seems there is no `SyncParametersClient` ore `AsyncParametersClient` like method in `rclpy` ? Thank you!

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-05**:\

> Also, seems there is no SyncParametersClient ore AsyncParametersClient like method in rclpy ?

Yes that is what I tried to say when saying " there is no helper and you need to create a service client yourself and call it". The fact thatthey don't exist make the example more verbose than in C++.

> Do you mind to give me a sample in python for this?

I replied on https://answers.ros.org/question/343322/ros2rclpy-how-to-set-parameter-hosted-by-another-node-via-service/ with a correction to your example

**Comment by [lin404](https://answers.ros.org/users/50033/lin404/) on 2020-02-05**:
@marguedas Thanks for your help a lot!

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-04-12**:
@mequi Did this answer solved your question?
If not can you comment with what information is missing.
If yes can you please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. This will remove the question from the unanswered list

**Comment by [kmilo7204](https://answers.ros.org/users/56520/kmilo7204/) on 2020-07-09**:
Just additional information for anyone who needs it **parameter.get_value();**

**Comment by [rela](https://answers.ros.org/users/150910/rela/) on 2023-05-23**:
i wanted to re-use infrastructure that expected a normal service client (not a `rclcpp::SyncParametersClient`) so i ended up building it like like a service to `/my_node_name/get_parameters` and called with `request->names.push_back("my_param_name")` and got it from the response at `response->values[0]` (in my case `response->values[0].string_value` (check size before accessing it))